# Reference constraint from this sketch cannot be used in FreeCAD

Tags: cad, software

I am using FreeCAD 0.20.2 in Ubuntu 22.04. I want to use a reference constraint to set the value of another constraint, but I it does not allow me. Why?

[image]

Comment: For questions regarding specific features of specific software, it might be better to ask in forums dedicated to that software. You try ["here"](https://forum.freecad.org/) if you don't receive an answer here.